# configure ssl certificate apache for 1 way authentication

Tags: java, apache, ssl

I am using java application to send request to a URL. I have an apache server in the middle. So my application sends request to the apache server and the apache server then sends request to the actual server with which I want to communicate.
The server side has sent us a .cer certificate file which should be presented at the time of SSL handshake. The server side is not ready to share the private key (.key) file with us. How do I configure the certificate in the apache httpd config.
Currently I have below configuration at httpd side
httpd.conf

```
< VirtualHost apache-server-IP:443 >

        SSLVerifyClient require
        SSLVerifyDepth 1
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/test.cer (certificate file provided by server side)

        ProxyPass /api https://ServerIP:ServerPort/api/oauth/token
        ProxyPassReverse /api https://ServerIP:ServerPort/api/oauth/token
< /VirtualHost >
```

I make a hit to the apache server using the URL (http://apache-server-ip:443/api/oauth/token) , which in turn sends request on https to actual server using proxypass.
I'm getting internal server error 500 from the server side.
Can anyone suggest how to configure the certificate in apache without using private key but only for presenting the certificate to the server.

Comment: "The server side is not ready to share the private key (.key) file with us." which is hopefully the true and unique way to do stuff, as named the private key has to stay private, otherwise anyone would be able to impersonate as anyone else.

Comment: "I'm getting internal server error 500 from the server side."  First reaction in cases like this: look at your logfiles they will give you more details on why the server replied with code 500. Or increase verbosity level.